# Actualizar JSON cada cierto tiempo

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tengo este código que obtiene el precio del oro (por ejemplo), pero quisiera que actualizara el precio cada 4 segundos sin refrescar la página completa.

He intentado hacerlo con este script pero no actualiza la URL del JSON:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#c2b').load('var2.php');
        refreshvar2();    
    });
    function refreshvar2(){
        setTimeout( function() {
            $('#c2b').fadeOut('slow').load('var2.php').fadeIn('slow');
            refreshvar2();  
        }, 2000);
    }
</script>

<div id='c2b'></div>
```

**var2.php**

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('https://data-asg.goldprice.org/dbXRates/EUR');
$decoded = json_decode($json);
$item = $decoded->items;
$date = $decoded->date;
$gold_price = $item[0]->xauPrice;

echo $gold_price."<br>";

$price_gr = $gold_price / "31.10"; //sacamos precio por gramo

echo $price_gr;

?>
```

Comment: En este caso, AJAX no es la mejor opción, pues si vas a estar pidiendo información al servidor constantemente, este se va a llenar de peticiones y se va a caer eventualmente, lo mejor es establecer una conexión socket

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario! pero a decir verdad no tengo ni idea de cómo podría implementarlo.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con _"pero no actualiza la URL del JSON"_? ¿Por qué llamar a un PHP que obtiene datos de otra página si puedes hacerlo directamente desde Javascript?

Comment: me refería a la url que está en 'file_get_contents' no estoy muy puesto en json y javascript. He ido haciendo según lo que iba entendiendo.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que debe cambiar en la URL? ¿O siempre devuelve lo mismo?

Comment: Eso ya lo he resuelto con no-cache. Estaba actualizando bien pero la caché no me dejaba ver el resultado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cambia en refreshvar2 setTimeout() por  setInterval() , asignalo a una variable que podrás poner a nulo si quieres desactivar la ejecución en el intervalo.